# Symfony2 Entity Annotation Assert/Callback method not invoked

Tags: symfony, callback, annotations, assert

I've got a problem with `Assert/Callback` validation. I used [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) as a sample for my code, but Symfony just ignores the validation function. This is the relevant part of my entity code

```
namespace Vendor\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo; // gedmo annotations
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;


/**
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isValidFirma"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Vendor\Bundle\Entity\UserProfileRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_profile")
 */
class UserProfile
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    //...

    public function isValidFirma(ExecutionContext $context){
        $context->addViolationAtSubPath('Firma', 'Company name must be present', array(), null);
        // as of sf 2.3 use addViolationAt() instead [reference: https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/issues/234 ]
    }    

    //...            

}
```

`isValidFirma` is never invoked. I tried validation.yml file instead of annotation as well, no success. I cleared the cache about fifty times, after every change, didn't help either. What could be the problem?

Comment: Why do you have two asterisks before the `@Assert\Callback` annotation?

Comment: It was a typo. Nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: Are you sure it is not called? Did you place something like `throw new \Exception(...)` inside the method to see if that will work? Anyway; you could always use `@Assert\True(message="your message") instead, that one works perfectly.

Comment: @Zeljko : yes, i tried it. It didn't do anything.

Comment: You tried exception or assert\true? Also put array("cascade_validation"=>true) in form class because in S2.1 it is turned off by default and maybe it has something to do with methods. I had big problems with embedded forms, that solved it. If nothing works, please put both the entity and form class (or controller) in another post for better visibility. You probably have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I seem to encounter the same problem.

Comment: yes, i answered my question just now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution. The problem was in used validator groups. The assert validator has to be a part of that group, or else it wont trigger.
This piece of code in form class file was the culprit:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $vg = array('my-profile');


    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => $vg
    ));
}
```

changing the line with assert to

```
* @Assert\Callback(methods={"isValidFirma"}, groups={"my-profile"})
```

did the trick.